# jQuery body html not updating with DOM

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I need to run a jQuery function to get all the html from the body of a web page. The problem is, when I use `$('body').html();` it just gives me the original HTML and not the current DOM HTML. So for example, I have a lot a blank textboxes, if I fill them in, and run this function, it returns the HTML with blank textboxes.

Answer (score 2):

No, `.html()` won't give you what you type in text boxes, you would need to use `val()` function instead to get typed value of text boxes and concatenate somehow to get desired result.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Decided to use jQuery to replace all the text boxes with a paragraph containing what was in the text box, and then getting the html. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ttamminen/QgBH4/) will give you an idea how to implement it. What you need to do is to serialize all form data and then go through name & value pairs and place them into your html.

I think this should not be done unless there is a really good reason. Maybe for some kind of spying application it's handy to take whole HTML with all the input values (including the hidden fields etc.)